# Increase worker_connections in nginx for AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to nginx configuration, I want to increase the worker_connections for my AWS Elastic Beanstalk API. The current worker_connections is set to 1024, I looked through all the nginx configurations I could find, still not working, kept saying invalid configuration. Do I extend a custom nginx conf file or override the default conf file? I tried both methods, none of them worked for me. Anyone know how to increase the worker_connetions for AWS Elastic Beasnstalk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I spent days on this and finally got it to work. It's not the nginx file problem, it's the nginx conf folder location problem. Moved the .ebextension folder from project root folder to the src/main/webapp folder and let Maven rebuild the spring boot WAR file and deployed, everything works now, ran stress tests with 200K+ requests without any issues.